# Remove any line that doesn't have dictionary format in python

Tags: python

I'm reading a multi-lines text file that has the format "variable:value" as dictionary in python; but I want to remove any line that doesn't have this format . I've tried this but the problem is if we have a line that contains colon but it's not in variable:value format it won't be removed . Any suggestions?
Code:

```
with open("file.setup",'r') as f_in:
    lines = [l for l in f_in if ":" in l]
with open("file.setup",'w') as f_in:
    f_in.writelines(lines)
```

file_to_read:/ra1/file.rpt
group_size:2
dpx:No
version:4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use regex here. I am assuming that *variable* can only contain numbers, letters and underscore and the *value* can be any characters.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\w+:.+")
>>> regex.search("file_to_read:/ra1/file.rpt")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 26), match='file_to_read:/ra1/file.rpt'>
>>> regex.search("group_size:2")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='group_size:2'>
>>> regex.search(":")
```

You could iterate over the lines and check against this regex to ensure that the line is in *variable:value* format.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"\w+:.+")
>>> with open("file.setup",'r') as f_in:
...     lines = [l for l in f_in if pattern.search(l)]
```

Comment: Thanks , how can I accept the format with space too , for example group_size : 2. I tried pattern = re.compile(r"\w+:.+").replace (" ","") but it didn't work.

Comment: You mean space between `:`?

Comment: yes. space between :

Comment: `re.compile(r"\w+\s?:\s?.+")`?

Comment: No, it didn't work

Comment: What is your string?

Comment: When more than one space in the left of ":" it didn't work 
for example: version (4 spaces)                              :4

Comment: `re.compile(r"\w+\s*:\s*.+")` This would work

Answer (score 0):

you could use regex

```
import re

# this pattern matches any two strings of letters either side of a colon
pattern = r'[a-zA-Z]:[a-zA-Z]'

with open("file.setup",'r') as f_in:
    lines = [l for l in f_in if re.search(pattern, l)]
```